# using clojure.contrib.strint with a string defined elsewhere

Tags: clojure, clojure-contrib

I'm new to clojure, and I'm trying to use clojure.contrib.strint to build a URL. for example I might use this for a google search:

```
(def search_base_url "http://www.google.com/search?hl=en&q=~{query}")

(defn search_url [search_term]
  (let [query (.replaceAll search_term "\\s+" "+")]
    (<< search_base_url)))
```

But this gives me the compiler error:
error: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No matching method found: indexOf for class clojure.lang.Symbol.
I think strint uses indexOf a few times, so somehow I'm not giving the << function what it wants, it seems.

I've also tried `(def search_base_url '(<< "http://myurl.com?~{params}"))`, but then I can't figure out how to evaluate that form in the context of my let. I could just put the string in the search_url function, but that feels inferior to me and I'm hoping the answer to this will help me understand clojure a bit better.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The problem is, that the "<<" macro expects a string, not something which evaluates to string.  That is, it tries to call .indexOf on the symbol named "search_base_url", instead of on its value.

So one way to fix this is:

```
(defn search-url [search-term]
  (let [query (.replaceAll search-term "\\s+" "+")]
    (<< "http://www.google.com/search?hl=en&q=~{query}")))
```

Answer (score 0):

I had a look at the source code for `<<` [on github](https://github.com/richhickey/clojure-contrib/blob/b9db2805f9571d52d5f0bb0b726fee1ca70c821d/src/main/clojure/clojure/contrib/strint.clj#L50) ... and I could not get it to work the way you want either.

BUT

If you re-write the macro like this:

```
(defmacro <<<
    [string]
      `(apply str (map #(eval %) (interpolate ~string))))
```

Then

```
(def query "queryitem")
(def basesearch "http://www.google.com/search?hl=en&q=~{query}")

(<<< basesearch)
```

Will return

```
"http://www.google.com/search?hl=en&q=queryitem"
```

Which is what you want.
Reason is:

```
 (interpolate basesearch)
```

returns a lazy-seq that does not perform evaluation of the sequence:

```
 ("http://www.google.com/search?hl=en&q=" query "")
```

The `query` symbol is never evaluated in the `<<` macro and is returned as is.

Since `silent-read` and `interpolate` are private you would have todo some copy paste but the final usage is quite cool.

Comment: This breaks down when `query` is eg. a let local. `<<` was explicitly designed to expand at compile time. Not runtime. Use `format` if you need that. Or construct the query string from pieces: `(<< "~{baseurl}?hl=~{language}&=~{queryitem}")`.